# SetState causing App crash in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have recently started working on **react.js**, while creating the login page I have used `setstate` method to set the value of `userEmail` to text box.

I have created a method which checks the validity of email address and I am calling it every time when user enters a new letter.

```
handleChangeInEmail(event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    console.log("change in email value" + value);
    if(validateEmailAddress(value) == true) {
      this.setState(function() {
        return {
              showInvalidEmailError : false,
              userEmailForLogin: value,
           }
     });
   } else {
     this.setState(function() {
       return {
              showInvalidEmailError : true,
              userEmailForLogin: value

      }
  });
}
```

This method and `userEmailForLogin` `state` is passed in `render` method as

```
<EmailLoginPage  
   userEmailForLogin = {this.state.userEmailForLogin}
   onHandleChangeInEmail= {this.handleChangeInEmail}
/>
```

I am using the method to validate the email address and the method is

```
validateEmailAddress : function(emailForLogin) {
        if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(emailForLogin))  {  
            return true; 
        }  
        return false;  
    },
```

I am using this method and state in render of **EmailLoginPage** as                           `<input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Email" className="email-input-txt" onChange={props.onHandleChangeInEmail} value = {props.userEmailForLogin}/>`

This is working fine in normal case , but when I try to input a large email addess say `yjgykgkykhhkuhkjhgkghjkhgkjhghjkghjghghkghbghbg@gmail.com`, it crashes

IMO the frequent change in state is causing this but I couldn't understand what should be done to get rid of this.

Comment: Why not just use the `this.setState({ });`

Comment: the way you are using is absolutely ok, but here callback inside `setState` is not required you can directly use `this.setState({})`, can you show how you are validating the email id?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes in the constructor

Comment: @MayankShukla: i agree but does it make any difference?

Comment: No it shouldn't, it should work in the same manner.

Comment: @Geek_To_Learn no, both are almost same except in few things. The way you are using is required when new `state` value is dependent on previous value but in your case new value is independent of prev one. Tell me one thing are you using any validation for email id or using the method exactly as you pasted in the ques?

Comment: @MayankShukla : I am using a validation method .

Comment: @Geek_To_Learn can you add the exact code you are using, since the problem doesn't lie in the code that you have addedin your question

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: Updated.

Comment: Any error in console

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri : nopes, actually after some letters it stops taking the input :(

Comment: I observed one thing that it stops when I press buttons continuously fase

Comment: @Geek_To_Learn check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/vedp/kp04015o/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think issue is with the `regex` only, i tried with other and it's working properly.

Instead of writing the `if/else` inside `change` function simply you are write it like this:

```
change(event) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
       showInvalidEmailError : this.validateEmailAddress(value),
       value: value,
    });
}
```

Copied the `regex` from this answer: [How to validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Check the working solution:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            value: '',
            showInvalidEmailError: false
        }
        this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    }

    change(event) {
        var value = event.target.value;
        this.setState(function() {
            return {
                showInvalidEmailError : this.validateEmailAddress(value),
                value: value,
            }
        });
    }
    
    validateEmailAddress(emailForLogin) {
        var regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        if(regex.test(emailForLogin)){
          return true;
      }
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.change}/>
                <br/>
                valid email: {this.state.showInvalidEmailError + ''}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>, 
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: But this approach will call setState for every changes.

Comment: is there any issue with this way of updating state?

Comment: No. but caling setState for each change should be avoided.

Comment: @Ved can you attach any link for reference? i don't think debounce is required  here.

Comment: Forget about debounce. Just think about the use case. if an email is of 20 characters, than you are calling setState 20 times.

Comment: @Ved if calling `setState` for each input change should be avoided then react doc should have mentioned that somewhere, i am referring doc only: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components i agree with your point but since setState is async and react  diffing algo is highly optimised, i don't think it will make a big difference.

Comment: You are going wrong way. have a look to this: https://medium.com/@justintulk/debouncing-reacts-controlled-textareas-w-redux-lodash-4383084ca090

Comment: "Say you have a controlled<textarea> with an onChange event that’s hooked up to a Redux action. That Redux action in turn is handled via some sort of async middleware like redux-promise-middleware. The problem is that every single character press fires off an action, which initiates an API request, which has to resolve before the view updates. Time to debounce.*"

Comment: Well, finally I got the issue. you were correct the regex operation was heavy which causes hanging the app. changed the validation of email, its working fine now

Comment: @Ved i think you are little bit confused with the article see: **1.** for each input change state is getting updated check `handleChange` function of point 3 of article again. **2.** why he is suggesting to use `debounce`: *The problem is that every single character press fires off an action, which initiates an API request* --> to avoid making the api call for each change he is using debounce (**avoiding multiple api calls not multiple setState**) handleChange function: `handleChange = e => {
    const val = e.target.value
    this.setState({ value: val }, () => {
     ......
}`

Comment: I have seen that. And that is one of the use cases. Anyway its all my approach to think and solve the problem. You have yours own.

Comment: @Ved i am not saying your answer is wrong, first time i heard this "avoiding setState for each input change" that why i asked for reference, btw thanks for telling this new thing :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution using debounce. This way multiple setState can be reduced.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/vedp/kp04015o/6/

```
class Email extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { email: "" }
    }

    handleChange = debounce((e) => {
        this.setState({ email: e.target.value })
    }, 1000)

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="widget">
                <p>{this.state.email}</p>
                <input onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

React.render(<Email/>, document.getElementById('container'));


function debounce(callback, wait, context = this) {
  let timeout = null 
  let callbackArgs = null

  const later = () => callback.apply(context, callbackArgs)

  return function() {
    callbackArgs = arguments
    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
  }
}
```

Comment: How can debounce be used in this case?

Comment: @Geek_To_Learn are you using lodash or underscore. Than I create a fiidle for approach one.

Comment: Not using lodash neither underscore

Answer (score 0):

You could use Lodash's debounce function so that the check function is not called unless the user stops typing for x amount of time (300ms in my scenario below).

```
_this.debounceCheck = debounce((value) => {
  if(validateEmailAddress(value)) {
    this.setState(function() {
      return {
        showInvalidEmailError : false,
        userEmailForLogin: value,
      }
    });
  } else {
    this.setState(function() {
      return {
        showInvalidEmailError : true,
        userEmailForLogin: value
      }
    });
  }
}, 300)

handleChangeInEmail(event) {
  _this.debounce(event.target.value)
}
```